# Stager iframe ticketshop embed wordpress

Tags: wordpress, iframe, ticket-system

So I'm embedding a ticketshop in my festival's website. This is all working fine except for when I interact with the embed, it opens the link instead of staying on page. How do I fix this?

you can check it out on here: (http://select.wesupplymarkting.com)

username: Demo
password: Select

The code I am using:
[image]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please add your code to the actual question so others can copy it easily to help you debug it, don't share a screenshot of it.

Comment: <iframe id="stager-ticketshop-iframe" height="800" width="650" frameborder="0" src="https://select.stager.nl/web/tickets/383988" style="border: 0px; background: transparent; max-width: 100%;"></iframe>